# Custom Screen Reader with custom TTS in iOS

Tags: ios, text-to-speech, screen-readers

I would like to add support for **Bangla** language for Screen Reader in iOS platform. The only available iOS Screen Reader VoiceOver app does not support this language. So my questions are:

1. Until Bangla is supported by VoiceOver, we have NO WAY to support the language? OR
2. We can somehow support Bangla language for Screen Reader in iOS (either by customizing VoiceOver settings or by developing new app)? If possible then-

   - Is it possible to add custom `TTS` with VoiceOver? If so, how can I configure it?   OR
   - Can I develop my own app, that will gather events/Utterance string/content from VoiceOver and will use a custom `TTS` to output Bangla voice? OR
   - Is there any way we can capture text content on the screen? I was googling for it, but the only thing I could find out is `AVSpeechSynthesizer`
     which is mainly used for voice-output in `TTS`, but I need to capture the screen text first.